# Force jQuery Mobile to update hash instead of URL for AJAX pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I am using the default behavior of jQuery Mobile where my href links are pointing to different pages on my site. This changes the URL completely. Is there a way to make it update the hash instead of changing the URL? The page alone does not work when going directly, so a hash would make sense (good for bookmarking). Also I would not have to worry about relative pathing from there since I remain in the root of my site. Any way to do this like it does for dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable this by setting `pushStateEnabled` to `false`.

This is done in `mobileinit` event. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
});
</script>

<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

Note that `mobileinit` must be attached **before**  jQuery mobile is included into page.
For more information take a look at [jQuery Mobile configuration defaults documentation page](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html).

Comment: FYI, this doesn't work with latest jquery-mobile, more over it corrupts all links to non-existing ones (by injecting `#` inside links). I ended up saving locally and "fixing" jquery-mobile by disabling this behavior (`useDefaultUrlHandling = false`)

Answer (score 1):

as for 1.4.5 version of jQuery Mobile, we found that additionally you need to set `changePage.defaults.changeHash` and `hashListeningEnabled` parameters to `false`

Example:

```
<script>
    $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
        $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
        $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    });
</script>
```

Source:
[jquery-mobile/no-hash-tests.html at cb9112abb3acf73abc104051ac318647055b189c · jquery/jquery-mobile · GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/cb9112abb3acf73abc104051ac318647055b189c/tests/integration/dialog-extension/no-hash-tests.html#L10)

Comment: This doesn't work either. I have a simple link to a simple image and jquery-mobile totally screws it up.